# How to connect my EXPO GO app in IOS to my django server? (both running on wsl)

Tags: django, react-native, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm doing a project using React Native/EXPO and Django. It's not my first time using Django, but it's my first time working on mobile development.

I have both of my repositories in WSL, but I can't find a way to consume an API from Django Server when I run the app on my Iphone (after reading the QR Code). I always get the same error:[AxiosError: timeout exceeded]. But if I try to consume this API with the WSL ip in postman, it works perfectly.

I know that it's an IP/Port problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I would really appreciate some help here.

**Django Server**

```
Settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

[image]

**React-native code**

```
login.tsx
    const handleLogin = async () => {
        const networkState = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync();
        console.log(networkState);
        const ipAddress = await Network.getIpAddressAsync();
        console.log('Endereço IP:', ipAddress);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://172.29.160.117:8000/api/token/', {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            });
            const accessToken = response.data.access;
            // Salve o token de acesso no aplicativo (por exemplo, no AsyncStorage)
            console.log("Resposta do servidor: " + accessToken);
            // navigation.navigate('ScreenHome');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            
        }
        console.log("Finalizou função");
    };
```

**Terminal Output**

[image: Terminal Output]